# How set form aciton to javascript:; on ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I  Request Form action using javascript.

But Page occured Error

`` undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass ``

```
<%= form_for message , url: "javascript:;" do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form-control", data: { textarea: "message" } %>
   <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary", data: { send: "message" } %>
<% end %>
```

I thinks `url: "javascript;;"` occured this error.

How to fixed these code?

Comment: In URL you need to specify  something. Whether you want to submit form by ajax call?

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary  Yes I wanna ajax Call

Comment: Then Specify URL same as other forms. Add Remote true to form tag <%= form_for(message, remote: true, format: :json, html: {class: :class_name}) do |f| %>

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary OK!!! Add ``remote: true``  then Working now~ :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want ajax call so use **remote:true**

```
<%= form_for message , remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form-control", data: { textarea: "message" } %>
   <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary", data: { send: "message" } %>
<% end %>
```